# Implementing a constructor for a derived class in a .cpp?

Tags: c++, xcode, class, constructor, derived-class

My question is very beginner, and yes I have looked it up extensively, but when I do the things I've found online Xcode gives me errors.

Basically, I'm just curious how to implement a constructor for a derived class.  My class is called "Sensor" and the derived classes are digitalSensor and analogSensor.

```
Here's my sensor.h:

    #ifndef __Program_6__sensor__
    #define __Program_6__sensor__

    #include <iostream>

    class sensor {
        char* SensorName;
        float energyDraw;
        int functioning;
        int onoff;

    public:
        sensor(char*n, float pc);
        virtual void print();

        void setOK(int K);
        int getOK();
        void setOnOff(int n);
        int getOnOff();
    };
    //---------
    class digitalSensor : public sensor {
        int reading;

    public:
        digitalSensor(char*n, float pc);
        virtual void print();
        void setCurrentReading(int r);
        int getCurrentReading();
    };

    class analogSensor : public sensor {
        int Reading;
        int minRead;
        int maxRead;

    public:
        analogSensor(char *n, float pc, int mm, int mx);
        virtual void print();
        void setCurrentReading(int r);
        int getCurrentReading();
    };


    #endif /* defined(__Program_6__sensor__) */
```

And here's my sensor.cpp, you can see the beginnings of my digitalSensor work at the bottom.

```
#include "sensor.h"
#include "definitions.h"
using namespace std;

//--------SENSOR CLASS------------//
sensor::sensor(char *n, float pc) {

    SensorName = (char*)malloc(strlen(n)+1);
    energyDraw = pc;
    functioning = WORKING;
    onoff = OFF;
}
void sensor::print() {
    cout << "     Sensor: " << SensorName;
    cout << "   Power Consumption: " << energyDraw;
    if (functioning == WORKING) {
        cout << "\nSensor is functioning correctly\n";

        if (onoff == ON) {
        cout << "Sensor is On";
    }
        if (onoff == OFF) {
        cout << "Sensor is Off";
    }

    }
    if (functioning == NOTWORKING) {
        cout << "Sensor is not functioning correctly";
    }
    }
void sensor::setOK(int k) {
    functioning = k;
}
int sensor::getOK() {
    return functioning;
}
void sensor::setOnOff(int n) {
    onoff = n;
}
int sensor::getOnOff() {
    return onoff;
}
//---------------------------------//

//*********DIGITAL SENSOR**********//

sensor digitalSensor::digitalSensor(char *n, float pc) {

}
```

In a nutshell: I need to make a constructor function for the digital sensor class.  What am I missing, how do I do that?  Thanks in advance for any help or knowledge on this!

Comment: This is important; don't ignore it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement its constructor like this:

```
digitalSensor::digitalSensor(char*n, float pc) : sensor(n, pc)
{
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't return anything and it calls its parent's constructor.

But you're doing this which is wrong:

```
sensor digitalSensor::digitalSensor(char *n, float pc) {
^^^^^^ constructors shall not return anything
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining that!  I get it now. Much obliged!

Answer (score 3):

You should call your base class constructor at the derived class's member initialization list.

For example:

```
   class digitalSensor : public sensor {
    int reading;

    public:
    digitalSensor(char*n, float pc): sensor(n, pc), reading(0){}
    virtual void print();
    void setCurrentReading(int r);
    int getCurrentReading();
  };
```

This defines the `digitalSensor` constructor inline. You can also define it with scope resolution operator outside class:

```
digitalSensor::digitalSensor(char*n, float pc):sensor(n, pc), reading(0){}
//^^Note that constructor of a class does not have any return type
```

It really depends on how your base class constructors are provided. But this could be one way to do it. You may find [Initializing base classes and members](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr388.htm) useful.